# The best place to put ReactiveBase or how many can you have

Tags: reactivesearch

I'm using ReactiveSearch to build out a Search UI. After trying lots of things... I'm trying to determine how to build my ReactiveSearch UI with the desired behavior.

Basically I'm trying to get the same behavior that both Google and Bing employ (or most search sites for that matter)... where users enter their query or use autocomplete on the home page and then search results are displayed on '/results' with a global Navbar that also a search input.

I originally had an Autocomplete component with both a ReactiveBase and DataSearch in it and a Results component with both a ReactiveBase and ResultList in it. It did not work as intended. The DataSearch did work but search did not function as expected (could not go from home page to results page with search working).

```
'/' - home component
<ReactiveBase
  ...
  <DataSearch
   ...
  />
</ReactiveBase>


'/results' - results component
<ReactiveBase
  ...
  <ResultList
   ...
  />
</ReactiveBase>
```

So now I'm trying to figure out how I can have a DataSearch in my home component at '/' and a ResultList in my results component at '/results' and only have 1 [ReactiveBase](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html) component in the app?